# Computed boolean column while creating table

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I'm trying to create table with computed boolean values

```
CREATE TABLE parts
(
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Weight INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(Weight > 0),
    Color VARCHAR(10),
    Price INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(Price > 0),
    IsCheap BOOL AS (CASE WHEN Price <= 1000 THEN True ELSE False END),
    Name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

But getting this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 7:  IsCheap BOOL AS (CASE WHEN Price <= 1000 THEN True ELSE Fal...
```

Also I've tried with BIT instead BOOL - same error. Have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: You need Postgres 12 for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Postgres 12 (released 2019-10-03) if you want to use computed columns.

And `as` on its own is not enough. The syntax requires to use `generated always as ...` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6.2.18.1.2):

```
create table parts
(
  id       serial primary key,
  weight   integer not null check (weight > 0),
  color    varchar(10),
  price    integer not null check (price > 0),
  is_cheap boolean generated always as (price <= 1000) stored,
  name     varchar(30)
);
```

---

If you are not using Postgres 12, then I would recommend to create a view that simply includes `price <= 1000 as is_cheap` as the calculation of that attribute is really cheap and there is no need to store it.